# Visual Studio C# Get sheet visible property

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, spreadsheet, visibility

I'm trying to fill a dictionary with name as key, and an array with codename and if sheet is visible. This is where I ran into a conversion issue with `sheet.visible`

If I use == true I get this error: [image]
if I use == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible like in the official Microsoft documentation, I get this error: [image]

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    private Dictionary<string, string[]> getSheetsDict()
        {
            Excel.Workbook wb =  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
            Dictionary<string, string[]> dSheets = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

            if (wb.Sheets.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Sheets)
                {
                    //string[] sDetails = { sheet.CodeName, Convert.ToString(sheet.Visible) };
                    string[] sDetails = { sheet.CodeName, (sheet.Visible == true) }; //Error 1
                    string[] sDetails = { sheet.CodeName, (sheet.Visible == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible) }; //Error 2
                    dSheets.Add(sheet.Name, sDetails);
                }
            }


            return dSheets;
        }
```

Comment: `(sheet.Visible == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible)` is correct, but it produces a bool. `sDetails` is an array of strings, so you have to assign a string to the initializer. Like `(sheet.Visible == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible) ? "yes" : "no" `

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed this, I come from VBA where boolean can be implicitly converted to String.
I defined the array as an array of Objects instead of Strings. Reverberated the change through my code and not it's running smoothly.

```
Object[] sDetails = { sheet.CodeName, sheet.Visible };
```